# Can you hide "bleeded area" in Print PDF?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, pdf

I've added .125 inches bleed to my A4 document and saved as High quality print from Illustrator.

[image]

Now if you see, top and bottom has some empty space. I know I could extend the image fully to bleed marks like I did on left and right (doesn't mean I haven't extended image on top and bottom. I did (1-2 mm), but very less as compared to left and right).

Now I'm pretty sure (I'm assuming printer knows artboard/document size so it will cut from there) it won't create problems while paper is cut, but it looks weird in PDF. Is it the default behavior of print PDF or can it be disabled in PDF, so that only artboard view is visibile? Also, will it create print problems?

Comment: If you are using bleed, make sure the artwork extends to the bleed marks on all sides. Not doing so defeats the point.

Comment: And why are you mixing units? It is either inches or mm, not both. First time you say .125 inches, then 1-2mm. Bleed unit needs to be the same as document unit.

Comment: @Lucian document shows inches. I used mm to describe how much area is extended on top and bottom.

Comment: If the document is set up in inches, use inches for everything related to this document. Be consistent. Assume you should probably be using a 0.125 inches bleed, but double-check with printer.

Comment: @Lucian I mean everything is in inches. I just casually wrote it in mm just to give idea how much is extended area in my document. Personally I can visualize 2-3 mm size. But I can't visualize decimal inches.

Comment: You **can** *crop* a PDF to the trim area and resave it...

Comment: Never heard that before o_O

Comment: FYI... Your Image has no bleed **marks** so it's hard to tell... but an important aspect of the bleed is... if you set up a .125" bleed then **all** images should **fully extend** to *cover* that .125". If, at the top and bottom of that image, you have *less* than .125" causing the white to show, you need to extend the image to cover the bleed area. Bleed settings are a *minimum* and not a *maximum*.

Comment: @Vikas looks like you need the original image to be gone for whatever reason. Note that it's still available in [the revision history](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/143995/revisions). You might need to flag a mod to redact the revision if it's a must.

Comment: @Scott must extend to avoid human error or any printer error? I understand human error, but I just can't understand printer error. Suppose print gives command to cut from trim area I can't imagine error.

Comment: Trimming is almost always done by humans. Especially for smaller press runs.

Comment: @Scott oh. I think my biggest misunderstanding so far was I assumed: When you give bleed to your document, an automatic machine built inside printer (not human) will cut the paper according to the bleed given, so there's not chance for human error. However, when in my PC I go to print command for a PDF, there's option to include 1) Trim Marks 2) Bleed Marks. I understand the importance of trim marks as it will be need to the print finisher, but I don't understand the need of bleed marks. I noted that this option of bleed marks is not found in Illustrator save settings.

Comment: To be frank **bleed** marks are largely superfluous and unnecessary. In most cases, they are there to merely *indicate* that a bleed **has** been considered/factored. Basically they provide, at a glance, knowledge that a bleed is included and that *all* bleed areas extend to at least the same minimum distance. Nothing is measured, trimmed, or done with *bleed* marks specifically.

Comment: I think someone suggested this already, but I would also suggest possibly calling a couple local print shops and asking if you can take a tour to see the entire process from delivery of artwork to printed piece. Most I've encountered would be happy to do this since it costs them nothing.

Comment: @Scott I'll try that once the pandemic is over :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have been asked to create a 0.125" bleed, then you should make sure the image fits the bleed or overlaps it slightly. If it doesn't extend all the way to the edge, then it will not technically be a 0.125" bleed.

If it doesn't quite reach, then enlarge the image slightly so that it does. When you save the PDF, in the export settings, add trim marks to make sure the print finisher knows exactly where to cut it, and set it to "Use document bleed settings". Note that the trim marks will be cut off anyway, and so won't be visible in the finished document.

[image]

Example

[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you please blur the main image? I posted original in hurry. Thanks.

Comment: print finisher = the guy who will use printer to print?

Comment: "Trim marks will be cut off anyway" does it mean the trim marks will get printed and later they'll cut them from paper?

Comment: I've blurred it now. The print finisher is the person who finishes the print job, i.e. guillotine, binding, etc. Yes the trim marks will get printed and cut off when the print job is trimmed using a guillotine.

Comment: It seems to me contradiction. We use bleed to avoid minute print errors. And we are adding trim marks, cutting them may also leave minute traces behind. Isn't it?

Comment: In other words, there are still chances of aesthetic error after even after using beeding.

Comment: Further, if I don't add trim marks, the guy/printer won't know where to cut?

Comment: This is the industry standard way of preparing a print job.  Do you think Adobe added these options for no good reason?  Look at the position of the trim lines, the corners get entirely cut away, there's no danger of the trim marks ending up on the finished print.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your message. It looks like a valid point and perhaps I misunderstood trim marks position. I'll cross check. Can you please let me know your views about my last query in previous message?

Comment: If you want to know more about printing and the processes involved it would do no harm to request a local print shop for a guided tour of their facilities. I was in the print trade (offset lithography) for over 20 years, and customers/designers often requested such visits. It can be difficult to design for print if you have absolutely no print knowledge.

Comment: Yeah I have very little knowledge. So far we don't use bleed. But I want to add it and learn it practically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118052/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-vikas).

Comment: @vik This might be part of what is confusing you: Trim marks are (or *should* be) offset from the trim by an amount equal to the bleed specifically so that they do not have any chance of showing once cut down. Adobe's default setting places them about half that so that they start in the middle of the bleed (or, at least, that *used* to be the default. I haven't had to deal with that in years). If your bleed is 1/8th inch, you should offset your trim marks by that much as well. Otherwise, you are right on that you might see the tips of a couple in the corners in the final product.

Answer (score 4):

### No, bleeds cannot be disabled from a PDF view.

A PDF either has bleed, or it doesn't. There is no "bleed on & off" button when looking at a PDF.

First, make sure you discuss this with the printer explicitly and understand what kind of PDF they need. In some cases they do not need a bleed on the PDF, otherwise you need to follow these steps and do not over think it:

- Fill the bleed area in your AI source file
- Send the PDF to print as it was requested: they know what to do with the bleed area. It is probably not the first time they see bleed on a PDF.
- Export another PDF without bleed for any other purposes where a bleed is not needed

Personally, when the bleed issue is not specifically requested, I will create 2 identical PDFs: one with bleed, one without bleed, and deliver both files.

Comment: Suppose if I sent bleed .125 inches. Does it mean they'll use same bleed for cutting? or there can be a mistake because their default bleed setting is say .250 inches? Is that why you want to say I should talk to printer person?

Comment: 0.125 inches bleed is kind of a standard in many places. 3mm in many other places. However, the printer should tell you how much bleed they need for their specific machines and settings. If you assume a value and send it anyway, without asking, they might be going back and asking for the files to be fixed to whatever bleed value they actually need. Never assume print specs unless you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

## No

This would just be a huge source of confusion because it assumes the person looking at a file knows that bleeds exist and have been hidden by the viewing software or not. This is why printer trim marks exist :)

A printer should quote the specs for a job ahead of time (or you should be aware of what print specs you're buying). If the quote says the printer is to produce, say, a thousand posters at the A4 final trim size, they will check (preflight) the file before printing to make sure that the files match the quoted specs. They're not about to print oversize and trim down for free.

Often, a printer will show you a proof of some sort to confirm that the final deliverable looks the way you intend. Sometimes that's a digital PDF, sometimes it's a physical mockup.

If they are printing to a given spec and your file has issues or does not match that spec, they should contact you to say "Hey, this job is not quoted to print oversize and trim down but your file is sized for an A4 sheet with 1/8th inch bleeds. Do you want us to just center the file on the A4 and crop the print design down to what fits within the printable margin? Scale it to fit? Send us a new file?"

I work at a printer and if a customer sends us a file that has bleeds but no printer marks to indicate where the trim lines are, we add them and show the customer a digital proof so they can see where it will trim (and so that everyone can confirm that bleeds are correctly built).

Of course, design customers don't always understand that the bleed is meant to be cutoff. I do freelance design work on the side and if I have a customer that isn't so savvy, I will show them a PDF proof without bleeds exported but then export a separate PDF, with bleeds and trim marks, that I give to the printer.

Comment: "we add them and show the customer a digital proof " you add them according to your default settings or according to the bleed amount give by customer in PDF?

Comment: @vikas We add trim marks for 1/8th inch bleeds because that's our standard bleed allowance. We dictate the minimum bleeds because we are the ones who have to fold signatures and trim the bound books. The customer doesn't get to determine how much bleed we use. If they give us 1/4 inch bleeds, then our marks would land in the middle of their bleeds because they have given us well over the 1/8th inch we need. If they give us less, we flag the problem to them so they can decide if they want to adjust their file or proceed as-is (knowing that some white will show on the edges).

Comment: in that case, why don't you just add trim marks to the document size simply? Why calculate that 1/8th inch stuff?

Comment: @vik I'm not sure I'm following. No need to calculate anything. InDesign and Illustrator document settings let you type in a bleed size and that creates the bleed box on your screen. When you export to PDF and select "add trim marks" they're added for the bleed size you entered automatically.

Comment: @vik Also: InDesign lets you toggle bleed visibility while you're working just like you are looking for. I think it's the W key by default. This doesn't affect how the file *exports*, though. That's driven by the export settings. I don't think this feature exists in Illustrator but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Ryara I'm considering the case when YOU have the PDF and customer forgot to add trim marks. So can't you just find the document size of PDF after opening it in Illustrator and add trim marks upto document size only? Instead of 1/8th of bleed.

Comment: @vik The PDF contains data on the [page trim box](https://support.activepdf.com/hc/article_attachments/360002748153/mceclip0.png), which is how preflight software recognizes where the trim marks need to be placed. If the PDF is exported without bleeds, the trim box/marks are still there but there would be no bleed. Also, you'd almost never send your Illustrator file to a printer :)

Comment: totally understood. So that is what I don't understand. My only confusion was related to when customer gives bleeded PDF and you place trim marks at 1/8th right?
Now in your last comment you agreed PDF has all the information, bleed, trim etc. So why don't you use just activate (print) the trim marks given by PDF, rather than setting your own according to bleed? If I've misunderstood you, please correct me, otherwise would live to get this confusion solved.

Comment: @vik Your last comment seems much clearer to me. I think it depends on the workflow of the company doing the printing and what stock they're printing on. A small copy shop is doing to ask "what size do you want?" You tell them A4. They open it up and see that it's oversize for an A4 by ⅛ inch in each direction because it has bleeds and realize they need to move up to an A3 and trim down to A4. If it has trim marks, they just print it. If not, they add them end then print it.

Comment: @vik But when you move up to a commercial printer, the workflow changes. They're printing on parent sheets (A0) and running files through an automated preflight first. Part of that automated preflight involves adding trim marks. Why? Because they don't always get them and and, if they do, they're not always setup correctly. If they are, it hurts nothing to reapply them. Sometimes, they might be able to get one more column or row out on the sheet if they use shorter marks. In that case, even if a file's original marks are fine in general, they need to be replaced for the tight imposition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118241/discussion-between-rykara-and-vikas).

Comment: oops looks like I missed a few messages from you. Chat doesn't exist any more :(

Answer (score 2):

### Don't do this.

...even if it turns out to be possible. In my opinion, there is never a need to do this, and it even encourages printing errors.

First off, I'd like to repeat what Billy says: if you are using the bleed area, fill it up completely. Not doing so defeats the point of using bleed and may end up confusing your printer. Possibly, getting your PDF rejected.

---

A print-ready, certified PDF (cPDF) is intended for print. All people who are going to look at this PDF are going to *need* to know the bleed area is there, and see its contents. If you hide it, they cannot do their work and print errors might be the result. It may look funny to you, but printers often need that bleed area

If you want a version of the PDF that looks good on screen, and doesn't have those 'funny' bleed and registration marks and all, make *another* version of the PDF, an 'Interactive' one.

cPDFs are not made to be looked at, they are made to be printed. 'Interactive' PDFs are made to be looked at and not to be printed. Use each as they are intended.

Comment: Oh. but I won't separately need to tell printer guy that there's some "extra artwork" in the PDF and you've cut from artboard/document dimension only? I mean he knows document size from PDF information, right?

Comment: Can printer get confused? o.O

Comment: @Vikas Printers are people. They can get confused. cPDFs are, usually and ideally, checked visually with human eyeballs before they go to production.

Comment: I still don't understand how can machine confused.